# How does the memory stack look for back to back recursive calls?

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to understand the concept of recursion. I understand how it works if there is one recursive statement in the code (example factorial)

I dont understand how code like this to calculate the depth of a binary tree would work:

```
public int getDepth(Node root)
{
    if ( root == null) return 0;

    int left = getDepth(root.left);
    int right = getDepth(root.right);
    if (left > right) 
       return left + 1;
    else
       return right + 1;
}
```

I see why this works but not how. Can someone explain to me how the second recursive call (getDepth(root.right)) works? What would this code look like in the memory? When getDepth(root.left) is recursive called does that stack ever go to the if statement at the every bottom?

Comment: Yes it will go back, when getDepth and all it subsequents recursive calls will have terminated.

Comment: Even recursive calls will end at some point (when `root == null` in this case), so yes, even code _after_ the recursive call will get executed.

Comment: Except if a StackOverflow or any other RuntimeExceptions happens, for sure.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard but when does getDepth(root.right) get executed?

Comment: @JonnyPeppers when getDepth(root.left) has returned.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard when getDepth(root.right) execute, will it also call getDepth(root.left) again?

Comment: If root is not null, yes it will call getDepth(root.left) again and getDepth(root.right), this will stop only when null root is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that each consecutive call to `getDepth` is completely separate and thus the bound variables are separate and it follows it's arguments and is oblivious that it's called from a version of itself with different arguments.

When you do `getDepth(null)` you get 0 since it's the very base case on the first line. However if you send it `getDepth(new Node(null, null))` it will call `getDepth(root.left)` which is the same as `getDepth(null)` and turns into 0 for both `left` and `right` and the result is `0 + 1`.

If you would bind the previous node to a variable `node` and try `getDepth(new Node(node, node))` it will do both `left` and `right` again where both of them would be the answer of the previous test 1. The result would be `1 + 1`, thus 2.

You can continue like this and just assume the result based on the previous calculations. By looking from a complex argument you need to imagine that each consecutive recursion starts fresh with it's arguments and that follows the same pattern. When a result is passed back the caller continues to the next line. In a tree structure like:

```
     1
    / \
   2   3
  /\   /\
 4  5 6  7
```

I just numbered the nodes and not included null nodes. You'll see the execution goes in this order. Identation indicates stack depth / how many calls are waiting to be resumed.

```
getDepth(1)
  getDepth(2)         // left
    getDepth(4)       // left
      getDepth(null)  // left base
      getDepth(null)  // right base
      return 0
    getDepth(5)       // right
      getDepth(null)  // left base
      getDepth(null)  // right base
      return 0
    return 0 + 1;
  getDepth(3)         // right
    getDepth(6)       // left
      getDepth(null)  // left base
      getDepth(null)  // right base
      return 0
    getDepth(7)       // right 
      getDepth(null)  // left base
      getDepth(null)  // right base
      return 0
    return 0 + 1;
  return 1 + 1;
return 2 + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to trace the execution if the tree consisted of only a single node (just the root node).

The stack would look something like this when `getDepth(root.left)` is called:

```
--->getDepth(root.left) //this will return 0 immediately, and will be popped of the stack
    getDepth(root) // this is your entry point
```

once, `getDepth(root.left)` returns, the stack looks like this:

```
--->getDepth(root) // this is your entry point
```

then the method at the top of the stack now will continue it's execution from where it was (it will now call `getDepth(root.right)`, and the stack will look like this:

```
--->getDepth(root.right) //this will return 0 immediately, and will be popped of the stack
    getDepth(root) // this is your entry point
```

again, once `getDepth(root.right)` returns, it will be popped off the stack and the calling method will continue it's execution and will then execute the last `if` statement.

The same pattern of execution will be followed for a tree with multiple nodes: eventually the recursive method calls will return (unless there is an exception) and the calling method will continue it's execution from the next statement.